# Express NodeJS: Append text / <p> element to a HTML file in POST

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to make a basic login system using Express, where if the user's username and password are correct according to a MySQL database, it adds a short "Success!" or "Failure" message to the bottom of the page when it receives a POST request.

I've tried using `res.write("<p>Success!</p>")` and `res.send("<p>Success!</p>")`, but neither have worked - instead they just create a new page with "Success!".

HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="/login">
            <label for="Username">Username: </label>
            <input name="Username" maxlength="45"><br><br>

            <label for="Password">Password: </label>
            <input name="Password" type="password" maxlength="45"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
const port = 3000;

const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    database: "database",
    user: "<Username>",
    password: "<Password>"
});

conn.connect((err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to database.");
})


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Login.html");
});

app.post("/login", (req,res) => {
    let form = req.body;
    let sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE Username = '" + form.Username + "' AND Password = '" + form.Password + "';";
    conn.query(sqlQuery, (err, result, fields) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(result.length == 1) {
            res.write("<p>Success!</p>")
        } else {
            res.write("<p>Failure.</p>")
        }
    })
});

app.listen(port);
```

So, how could I append a short *p* element / text to the bottom of an HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Okay,
So when the submit button in the login form is hit, it creates a totally new request and the old page is no longer in the context of request.

So, res.write() creates a new page, since a new request is generated.

If you want to append the failure and success messages on the same page, you can use ajax request instead of default form submission.

Send the ajax request, you will receive the response without a page reload, and then upon receiving the response, using javascript, you can append a new element with message from the server

```js
const contactForm = document.getElementById('contact-form');
contactForm.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = contactForm.elements['username'].value;
    const password = contactForm.elements['password'].value;

    // now make the ajax call, you can use any library like FetchAPI, axios or even jQuery Ajax
    fetch('http://backend/endpoint',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({username,password})
        })
        .then((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        })
        .then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
            // you can append new element here
            // based on data (success or failure)
        })
})
```